# I cannot sign into my drupal site. The login page just refreshes and there are no error messages

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I cannot login into any account from the login page. I can get to the admin page by `doing drush user-login` but if I log out of admin and try logging in again, the login page just refreshes and I do not get signed into the account; no errors messages, even if I put in an incorrect username and/or password. After nuking my local repo a couple times, I found out that if I put in the wrong username and/or password or if I log in and out a bunch of times, I will not be able to sign in to any other account. The login page will just refresh.

I tried doing stack traces using `debug_print_backtrace()` in the UserLoginForm.php located in core/modules/user/src/form but my computer just freezes. Normally, when I actually log into an account, the console on the browser under network shows a 303 which redirects, but when I cannot login, that request is not present. I've cleared cache, cleared cookies, tried different browsers, but nothing seems to work. The watchdog log messages just say a session has been started by a user and

`Notice: Undefined index: function in Drupal\Core\Database\Log->findCaller() (line 154 of /app/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Log.php)`.

I'm making a custom theme and module if that helps. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So after failing to log in a couple times, drupal will block your ip and makes it so you can't login until some arbitrary amount of time, which explains a lot. To unblock ip addresses use `drush sql-query "delete from flood"` I also did not have the error messages popping up when you put in a wrong password.